# Insert Into Table on Submit

Tags: c#, razor

I'm a little confused as to how to write C# razor. I keep getting **"The name 'Datetime' does not exist in the current context"**

Do I have to declare that and everything else?

```
@{
var db = Database.Open("Records");
var insertQuery = "INSERT INTO Entries (Datetime, Title, FirstName, LastName, Categories, Centers,     Status, Comments) " + 
"VALUES (@1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6, @7, @8)";
db.Execute(insertQuery, Datetime, Title, FirstName, LastName, Categories, Centers, Status, Comments);
Response.Redirect(@Href("~/List"));}
```

The rest of it, just s simple form.

```
   <body>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Create An Entry</legend>
```

The current date and time.

```
        <div>
            <label for="Datetime">@DateTime.Now</label>
        </div>
```

A Title.

```
        <div>
            <label for="Title">Title:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Title" value="" />
        </div>
```

First Name.

```
        <div>
            <label for="FirstName">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="" />
        </div>
```

Last Name as well.

```
        <div>
            <label for="LastName">Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="LastName" value="" />
        </div>
```

I figure some categories to chose from.

```
        <div>
         <label for="Categories">Categories:</label>
            @{
                var categories = new List<SelectListItem>{
                    new SelectListItem {Value = "1", Text = "1"},
                    new SelectListItem {Value = "2", Text = "2"},
                    new SelectListItem {Value = "3", Text = "3"}
                };
            }
            @Html.ListBox("CategoriesListbox", categories, null, 4, true) 
        </div>
        <br/>
```

Just added another list to chose from.

```
        <div>
            <label for="Center">Center:</label>
            @{
                var centers = new List<SelectListItem>{
                    new SelectListItem {Value = "1", Text = "1"},
                    new SelectListItem {Value = "2", Text = "2"},
                    new SelectListItem {Value = "3", Text = "3"},
                    new SelectListItem {Value = "4", Text = "4"},
                    new SelectListItem {Value = "5", Text = "5"}
                };
            }
            @Html.ListBox("CenterListbox", centers, null, 6, true) 
        </div>
        <br/>
```

And another for good measure.

```
        <div>
         <label for="Status">Status:</label>
            @{
                var status = new List<SelectListItem>{
                    new SelectListItem {Value = "1", Text = "1"},
                    new SelectListItem {Value = "2", Text = "2"},
                    new SelectListItem {Value = "3", Text = "3"}
                };
            }
            @Html.ListBox("StatusListbox", status, null, 4, true) 
        </div>
        <br/>
```

And a place for comments before submitting.

```
        <div>
            <label for="Comments">Comments:</label>
            <textarea name="Comments" cols="20" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>&nbsp;</label>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" />
        </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
```

Or is there a simple mistake I made somewhere?

Comment: How are you going to reference the database after the page is rendered on the client?

Comment: I was thinking of redirecting to another page, and just retrieving the records from there. I wanted to try and get it in there first.

Comment: Why not use ASP.Net MVC?

Comment: Just trying something new.